# How to write an efficient code for the following tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code for a tic-tac-toe game and it works well. But, I don't know whether it is an efficient one. Any help on how to optimize it?

```
def restart():

    num=[0 for i in range(9)]
    board=[" " for i in range(9)]
    a=2
    start(board,a,num)

def wincheck(t):

    for i in range(8):
        if t[win[i][0]]==t[win[i][1]] and t[win[i][0]]==t[win[i][2]] and 
                            t[win[i][1]]==t[win[i][2]] and t[win[i][0]]!=" ":
            if t[win[i][0]]=="X":
                print("Player 1 wins")
            else:
                print("Player 2 wins")
            playa = input("Do you want to play again? Y/N")
            if playa.lower() == "y":
                restart()
            else:
                exit(0)
def display_board(t,a,num):

    print( " "*3+'|'+" "*3+'|'+" "*3) 
    print("{0:^3}|{1:^3}|{2:^3}".format(t[6],t[7],t[8]))
    print( " "*3+'|'+" "*3+'|'+" "*3) 
    print("-"*11)
    print( " "*3+'|'+" "*3+'|'+" "*3) 
    print("{0:^3}|{1:^3}|{2:^3}".format(t[3],t[4],t[5]))
    print( " "*3+'|'+" "*3+'|'+" "*3) 
    print("-"*11)
    print( " "*3+'|'+" "*3+'|'+" "*3) 
    print("{0:^3}|{1:^3}|{2:^3}".format(t[0],t[1],t[2]))
    print( " "*3+'|'+" "*3+'|'+" "*3)
    wincheck(t)
    if 0 not in num:
        print("Draw")
        restart()
    start(t,a,num)

def start(board,a,num):

    if a%2==0:
       p1n=int(input("Player 1, Enter a number from 1 to 9"))
       if p1n not in num:
           num[p1n-1]=p1n
           print(num)
       else:
           print("Please enter in a free space")
           start(board,a,num)
       board[p1n-1]="X"
       a=a+1
       display_board(board,a,num)
    else:
       p2n=int(input("Player 2, Enter a number from 1 to 9"))
       if p2n not in num:
           num[p2n-1]=p2n
           print(num)
       else:
           print("Please enter in a free space")
           start(board,a,num)
       board[p2n-1]="O"
       a=a+1
       display_board(board,a,num)


a=2

board=[" " for i in range(9)]

num=[0 for i in range(9)]

win = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,4,8],[6,4,2],[6,3,0],[7,4,1],[8,5,2]]

start(board,a,num)
```

Comment: This seems more suited to [CodeReview.StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).